# HTML displaying for loop elements faster

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I have around 800 items in a dictionary that I am displaying on a web page. The page loading is becoming super slow- taking about 40 sec. Any help how I can make this faster? I am not much experienced with html. Can javascript help in making it faster?
This is what I have-

```
{% for dev, need in dev_firm.items %}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2"><a href="{% url 'inv:dev_view' dev %}">{{ dev }}</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-2">{{ need|updatestatus }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

dev_firm is a django variable.

Comment: Its slow because you are trying to load 800 items. You need to implement paging. When your PHP code is executed, it is looping through 800 elements and generating markup, that is why it takes so long to load.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine - I agree with your comment, but note that this isn't PHP

Comment: @RobinZigmond good catch, should've read the question better haha.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with Django, however I wouldn't try speeding this up on the client side, as long as you have to call every element separately, it will make things much worse (800 JavaScript `fetch()` calls i.e. would be the worst you could do to a web app).

Depending on your server environment, you should think about storing all the dictionary entries in a usable format on your server. This way it would be only a single file that the user would download directly.
If you want to parse and display this file on the client side using JavaScript, you'd need to run a script compiling all the entries to a `JSON`-file, whenever the dictionary is updated. Depending on your server environment such a script could be a piece of `PHP` hooked into your content management system or a service written i.e. in `python` that runs whenever you tell it to.
If you prefer other languages you could simply generate a static `HTML` using the same method.

The main issue in your logic here is that you want to compile the file when the data is called. There are many reasons, why you should provide your user with a file that was compiled when the data was created.
Read more: https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-crud